# Issue passing value between javascript and php - Popup PHP Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to incorporate a popup into my project. It works up until I try and pass a value from javascript to the php script. I have included a link to the example I used and link to the original script. There were slight changes made to the original script. The area I am having an issue with is marked with a ---->

full script can be found here:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?279111-Contact-form-popup-window

working example can be found here:
http://ilolo.ru/wd/contact_form/

I have the following in hello.html

```
<form id='form1' style='width: 1100px'>
    <table>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Options</th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='email1' size='25' value='bob@mail.com'>
            </td>
            <td><a id='1' href='#null' class='contactus'><img src= 'images/emailbutton.jpg'    title='Email' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></a>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The following js is in a .js that I reference in my html.
I use the following since I have more than one form. Just showed one form in my example.
The alert below works....shows the correct email address when I click on the image link in the html.

```
    function findCenter(obj) {
        var deltaX = parseInt(obj.css('padding-left')),
            deltaY = parseInt(obj.css('padding-top'));
        obj.css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - obj.width() / 2 - deltaX + 'px').css('top',  $(window).height() / 2 - obj.height() / 2 - deltaY + 'px');
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.contactus').click(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var J = element.attr('id');
    var email = document.getElementById('email'+J).value;
        alert(email);
        $('#result').html('<h3>Loading</h3>').css('display', 'block');
        findCenter($('#result'));
        $.get('email.php', function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            findCenter($('#result'));
            $('#snd').click(function () {
                var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
                var addy = document.getElementById('addy').value;
                var comments = document.getElementById('comments').value;
                     $('#result').append('<br /><br /><div><i>Sending...</i></div>');
                     $.post('lbi_email.php',{mode: 'snd', subject: subject, addy: addy, comments: comments},function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
                findCenter($('#result'));
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
```

email.php

This value below is not getting sent by the javascript and the input value=$email is not written correctly (I think)

```
<?php 
include( 'connection.php'); 
function showForm(){ 
$email=$_POST[ 'email'];  
echo '<form name="mf" id="mf" action="" method="post">
    <h2>Send Email To Customer</h2><br />
    <p><label>Address :</label><input type="text" size="35" name="addy" id="addy" value="'.$email.'"/></p>
    <p><label>Subject :  </label><input type="text" size="35" name="subject" id="subject" value=""/></p>
    <label>Message:</label><textarea style="width: 100%;" cols="20" rows="10" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn" id="snd" name="snd"><img src="submitbutton.jpg" title="Submit Email" border="0" height="25" width="75"></img></a></p></form>';
   } 

function sndForm(){ 
/* here goes checking data and so on... then sending if everything 's good and sending done show message to the user*/
    echo '<h3>Everything\'s cool.
    <br />
    <br />Viva Cuba!</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(\'$("#result").fadeOut("fast")\',3000);
    </script>'; 
} 
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
 $mode=(!empty($_GET['mode']))?$_GET['mode']:$_POST['mode']; 
switch($mode)
{ 
case 'snd':sndForm();break; 
default: showForm();break; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Dude, indent your code. It's nigh unreadable like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you are sending literal `email` instead of your `email` value -

```
$.post('email.php',{mode: 'snd', email: 'email'},function(data){
```

Change this to -

```
$.post('email.php',{mode: 'snd', email: email},function(data){
```

In your php code you have a variable scope issue - `$email` is outside the scope of your function

```
$email=$_POST[ 'email']; 
function showForm(){ 
echo $email;
```

Try setting it inside

```
function showForm(){ 
$email=$_POST[ 'email']; 
echo $email;
```

Finally, you have `$email` inside single quotes-

```
echo '<form name="mf" id="mf" action="" method="post">
    <h2>Send Email To Customer</h2><br />
    <input type='text ' value='$email '/> 
    ...
```

Need to update to

```
echo '<form name="mf" id="mf" action="" method="post">
    <h2>Send Email To Customer</h2><br />
    <input type="text" value="'.$email.'"/>
    ...
```

---

Additionally, it looks like when you are submitting the for you are not sending the comments textarea, so you probably need to add that as well.

```
$('#snd').click(function () {
        $('#result').append('<br /><br /><div><i>Sending...</i></div>');
        var comments = document.getElementById('comments').value;
        $.post('email.php',{mode: 'snd', email: email, comments: comments},function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
                findCenter($('#result'));
        });
});
```

---

Edit

You need to add the `email` value to your `$.get()` -

```
$.get('email.php', email: email, function (data) {
```

and then change it to `$_GET['email']` in your php -

```
function showForm(){ 
$email=$_GET[ 'email'];
```

Comment: Hey Sean...thanks for the response. Here is what I found after making all your suggested changes...it doesn't like when I added comments: comments. The form freezes. When I hit the email button now to pop up the form the email address from javascript still does not show in the php...I just see the word "echo" show up on the form. Thanks,  Kurt

Comment: A quick update...figure out the echo issue but the value is still not getting passed from javascript to the php.

Comment: Hey Sean - the email address is not showing in the input box on showForm.  I have not yet added code to actually send the email. Will be working on that now.  Thanks,  Kurt

Comment: It justs looks like the email address value gets lost when the form shows.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your updated `showForm()` function.

Comment: Hey Sean......I will update all my code.  I was thinking...maybe we need to look at the $('.contactus').click(function(){ instead.  Where are we actually posting $email to the php script?  Kurt

Comment: Sean - I updated the code and moved the comments outside of the code.  This is what I currently have.  I have also added code to send an email, which has been tested and works.  The only issue I have with this is I can not pass the email value from javascript to the $_POST in php which then fills the input box value with email value.  Thanks, Kurt

Comment: You are not sending your email value in your `$.get()`. See my edit.

Comment: I added your edits. When I add email: email to the following...the form no longer pops up.  $.get('email.php', email: email, function (data) {  I do not understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: it sounds like there is a syntax error. Check your browser developer tools/console.log. You could also add it to your url -> `$.get('email.php?email='+email, function (data) {`

Comment: Sean - got it working with your last suggestion....thank you very very much.  Kurt